# How to call another view, Im using Leanback with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, leanback, smart-tv

I dontknow how to call another view, Im devoloping an app for smart tv, the technologies are android,kotlin and leanback library, I trying to do click in my cardview called "Lecciones" when i clicked there i need to call to my view Lesson

this is my code

```
class MainActivity : FragmentActivity() {


    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        setContentView(view)




        /**   binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, EaActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

        }
         */
    }
}
```

```
data class Content(var title: String, var poster: String)
class MainFragment : BrowseSupportFragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        title = getString(R.string.browse_title)

        val rowsAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(ListRowPresenter())


        val categoryTitles = listOf(
            "LECCIONES",
            "EJEMPLOS",
            "EJERCICIOS",
            "EVALUACIÓN"
        )


        val titlesPerCategory = 1

        onItemViewClickedListener = OnItemViewClickedListener { _, item, _, _ ->
            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), Lesson::class.java).apply {
                // pass the item information
            }
            startActivity(intent)


        }

        (1..4).forEach { categoryId ->
            val categoryTitle = categoryTitles[categoryId - 1]

            val listRowAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(CardPresenter())

            listRowAdapter.addAll(0, (1..titlesPerCategory).map { index ->
                val title = generateTitle(categoryId, index)
                Content(
                    title,
                    "https://c.pxhere.com/images/15/da/2135fc8acd22bb3f6ae67c79fe53-1449505.jpg!d"

                )

            })
            val header = HeaderItem(categoryId.toLong(), categoryTitle)
            rowsAdapter.add(ListRow(header, listRowAdapter))




            adapter = rowsAdapter


        }


        onItemViewClickedListener = OnItemViewClickedListener { _, item, _, _ ->
            val intent = Intent(requireContext(), Lesson::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }


    }

    fun generateTitle(categoryId: Int, index: Int): String {
        return when (categoryId) {
            1 -> "Lección  - $index"
            2 -> "Ejemplo - $index"
            3 -> "Ejercicio - $index"
            4 -> "Evaluación $index"
            else -> "Título Categoría Desconocida - $index"
        }
    }
}
```

## i need call the other view, the other view is FragmentBrowser, the class call lesson

Comment: You need to explain what you want better, there is no such thing as "calling a view".  Do you want to keep the same activity and swap out the entire (or large portion of) the UI?  Fragments may be the way there, but there are negatives to them as well.  Do you want to display a new activty?  And Intent and startActivity is the answer then.